# Translation from Python to R. Big difference in execution time

Tags: python, r, for-loop, while-loop, vectorization

I am translating a piece of code from Python to R to locate the position of a series of numbers when the sum duplicates. The translation is to me one-to-one, but the python code takes less than a second to execute compared to the R code which takes around an hour. I wonder if I miss anything in the data structure of both languages. Why is there such a big time difference in executing the codes? What could be a better or efficient alternative when I write the following Python code in R?

Python:

```py
def calculate(data):
    found = set([0])
    total = 0
    while True:
        for num in data:
            total = total + num
            if total in found:
                return total
            else:
                found.add(total)
```

R:

```r
calculate <- function(input) {
  found = set(0)
  total = 0
  while (TRUE) {
   for (num in input) {
     total = total + num
     if (total %in% found) {               
         return(total)
     } else {
         found <- c(found, total)
     }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Unlike many languages, R typically does at least *a little* better in vectorized operations vice unrolling them into a `for` loop (many, perhaps most languages perform better in a `for` loop). Most questions I've seen claiming recent versions of R do very poorly in the `for` loop had some gargantuan inefficiencies in the code, or were being punished by iterative binding or R's reference semantics.

Comment: where's `set` coming from in your R code?

Comment: @SamMason, the `set` is from this package: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/sets/versions/1.0-18/topics/set. I did not include it in the above code.

Comment: Usually, in R, you don't have to use loops. You have to split a problem and match each of the subproblems to a function in R. In your example you could use R's build-in cumsum.

Comment: @FannieY could you give a small example where you see this difference in execution time, and maybe also explain the point of this algorithm?  the few examples I've tried either halt immediately or diverge and I don't see how it would ever halt

Comment: @SamMason, thanks for your trial. It's actually an exercise I took from here: https://adventofcode.com/2018/day/1. The input will be `fileName <- "D1L1.txt"conn <- file(fileName, open = "r")linn <- as.numeric(as.character(readLines(conn)))`. In some small sample cases we do not see the execution time difference. In this example the solution is achieved after looping over 135000 times, therefore I am looking for efficient way to do it in R. The alternative of %in% is.element(x, y) does not seem to work better.

Answer (score 1):

at a guess this is a combination of most things being immutable in R  (hence the vector concatenation will be allocating new objects every time) and R's `%in%` operator being O(N), compared to `in` being O(1) in Python